# The processing of a file using Javascript never completes

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function whose purpose is to load a file once the user selects one. The function looks like this:

```
function setupFileListener() {
    document.getElementById('Attachment').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        var file = document.getElementById('Attachment').files[0];
        if (file) {
            processFile(file);
        }
    })

    const processFile = (file) => {
        alert("Processing file");

        const fr = new FileReader();

        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        fr.onloadend = () => fileLoaded;
    }

    const fileLoaded = (e) => {
        alert("File loaded");

        const fr = e.target
        var result = fr.result;

        console.log(result)
    }
}
```

The alert() function fires correctly when processing starts but I never get alert() to fire when the file is loaded. So it appears fileLoaded never gets called. I'm running this in Chrome and no Javascript errors are being generated.

Can anyone see what might be wrong?

Comment: What if you set the event handler (`onloadend`) before reading the file (`readAsDataURL()`)?

Comment: fileLoaded(e) instead of fileLoaded

Comment: Maybe add () to fileLoaded ? . [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ejpnatv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke the function instead of just returning it inside the  onLoadEnd event

```
   const processFile = (file) => {
        alert("Processing file");

        const fr = new FileReader();

        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        fr.onloadend = (e) => fileLoaded(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be this line =>

```
fr.onloadend = () => fileLoaded; to
fr.onloadend = () => fileLoaded();
```

```js
function setupFileListener() {
   document.getElementById('Attachment').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        var file = document.getElementById('Attachment').files[0];
        if (file) {
            processFile(file);
        }
    })

    const processFile = (file) => {
        alert("Processing file");

        const fr = new FileReader();

       fr.readAsDataURL(file);
       fr.onloadend = (e) => fileLoaded(e);
       
    }

    const fileLoaded = (e) => {
        alert("File loaded");

        const fr = e.target
        var result = fr.result;

        console.log(result)
    }
}

setupFileListener()
```

```html
<input type="file" id="Attachment">
```